# Salesforce Integration with Square - 302 Found Error

Tags: rest-api, integration

I am attempting to create a REST integration with Square (https://developer.squareup.com), but am receiving a 302 Found error when I attempt to send a webhook via Square.

My API is working successfully when tested through Workbench with the payload that is being sent via Square, at the URI of `/services/apexrest/[SOBJECTNAME]/[RESTRESOURCENAME]`.

My endpoint URL is as follows:
`https://ORGNAME--partial.lightning.force.com/services/apexrest/[SOBJECTNAME]/[RESTRESOURCENAME]` which generates a 302 Found error, meaning that the endpoint is redirecting. I am unable to process the redirect via Square.

I have tried playing around with different base URLs for the endpoint per the [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_rest_resource.htm) and other forum posts, for example `ORGNAME--partial.my.salesforce.com` (401 unauthorized), `ORGNAME--partial.INSTANCE.my.salesforce.com` (307 redirect), and `ORGNAME--partial.INSTANCE.force.com` (401 unauthorized) to no avail. I am unable to use `ORGNAME--partial.salesforce.com` for the subscription endpoint per Square.

Hoping someone has run into this issue before. Thank you!

---

Following up on identigral's comment, I have created a Site with the value of `https://ORGNAME-square.INSTANCE.force.com/square/` and have updated my webhook endpoint accordingly to `https://ORGNAME-square.INSTANCE.force.com/square/services/apexrest/[SOBJECTNAME]/[RESTRESOURCENAME]`. Now getting a code of status 500 Internal Server Error.

I should add that I also have a Remote Site Setting with the appropriate value of `https://connect.squareupsandbox.com`.

Comment: It works in Workbench because you're authenticated. For a typical webhook, your REST endpoint must be public - see answer by gils in [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/238073/creating-an-endpoint-in-salesforce-for-our-external-service-to-access-data) Q&A for a howto

Comment: Hello @identigral! I have a site set up now and am getting a 500 error.

Comment: It's unclear on what API you're calling after you've created the Site and what your webhook is doing. Please edit your question and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Help Center](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for guidance on this.

Comment: What is the urlMapping you've specified in your `@restResource` annotation?

Comment: Hi @DerekF, the urlMapping is /[SOBJECT]/[RESTRESOURCENAME], as specified in the URI. I have verified spelling and capitalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just posting the follow up as to what the issue was. We were able to solve this via @identigral's comment of setting up a site and debugging through the Site Guest User. The resulting 500 error was caused by Square sending the same payload multiple times and duplicate detection bouncing it back.